# Convert type from string to string array

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode

I want to remove schedule notifications from my app for this I need String array to remove pending notifications I have this type of string its not array this return String from fbdb database but I want array

```
 ["01D94B0E-F1AB-421E-9EC3-4A78F0211ED8",
 "76E16E51-CB59-4D3F-939E-4D492FFB22BE",
 "97696EBD-252F-4A12-962E-995EF306B557",
 "84EB98BB-14EB-4D19-83F6-798DCF75E3CD",
 "B55621AE-B124-4767-8D6E-C728598E5279"]
```

I have this is in Array format how can I do this? I know this is beginner question hope u guys will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let str = """["01D94B0E-F1AB-421E-9EC3-4A78F0211ED8", "76E16E51-CB59-4D3F-939E-4D492FFB22BE", "97696EBD-252F-4A12-962E-995EF306B557", "84EB98BB-14EB-4D19-83F6-798DCF75E3CD", "B55621AE-B124-4767-8D6E-C728598E5279"]"""
let ids = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: Data(str.utf8)) as? [String] ?? []
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use default JSONDecoder...

```
import Foundation

var stringToData: Data? = "[\"01D94B0E-F1AB-421E-9EC3-4A78F0211ED8\", \"76E16E51-CB59-4D3F-939E-4D492FFB22BE\", \"97696EBD-252F-4A12-962E-995EF306B557\", \"84EB98BB-14EB-4D19-83F6-798DCF75E3CD\", \"B55621AE-B124-4767-8D6E-C728598E5279\"]".data(using: .utf8)

let decoded = try JSONDecoder().decode(Array<String>.self, from: stringToData!)
print(decoded)
```

output:

["01D94B0E-F1AB-421E-9EC3-4A78F0211ED8", "76E16E51-CB59-4D3F-939E-4D492FFB22BE", "97696EBD-252F-4A12-962E-995EF306B557", "84EB98BB-14EB-4D19-83F6-798DCF75E3CD", "B55621AE-B124-4767-8D6E-C728598E5279"]

Answer (score -2):

You can try

```
let str = """ 
["1","2","3"]
"""
let res = str.dropFirst(1).dropLast(1)
let arr = res.components(separatedBy: ",").map { $0.replacingOccurrences(of: "\"", with: "") }
```